# Text to speech and Orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, text-to-speech

My application makes heavy use of the `Text to Speech API`.

It is a game which leads the player to change the orientation frequently. I do have different layouts for portrait and landscape and this is ok.

I use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `onCreate()` to keep the state.

However, there is one fact that causes problems:

I am calling `tts.shutdown()` in `onDestroy()` which I think is necessary to free resources properly. However, this causes the current text and all queued messages to be lost when the user changes the orientation. As the Text-to-Speech object has a reference on the "***old***" activity, I cannot transfer it to the new activity.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a good use for the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class, where you initiate the TTS in `onCreate()` (and forget about it, as onTerminate() is not called on real devices).

Comment: thanks, but I need the startActivityForResult() method to check the TTS like in http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/speakToMe.html. Any way to get this method from a service?

Comment: TTS has two phases 1) initializing+shutdown 2) talking. 1. is what I propose to do globally once per start. 2. can still be done in individual activities. But then I probably misunderstood you.

Comment: There's a potential memory leak here. The TTS object is created with a reference to a context. If the TTS object is preserved between config changes and it was created with the activity as the context, then this will cause a memory leak (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)). Perhaps one could use the Application object as the context, although I haven't experimented with this.